# Java, cannot find symbol : method methodName(org.bla.blabla.myClass)

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene APIs, and I get the following error on this line of my code:

```
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable;

...

Document _document  = new Document();
_document.add(new Field("type", document.getType()));
```

Error:
CollectionIndexer.java:34: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(org.apache.lucene.document.Field)
location: class CollectionIndexer.Document
        _document.add(new Field("type", document.getType()));

This is the documentation about the method:
http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#add(org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable)

thanks

Update: javac -cp commons-digester-2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar:lucene-core-3.0.3.jar myApp.java

Comment: On what object do you call the myMethod method?

Comment: There's hardly enough information here to suggest anything sensible!  Can you add a minimable (non)-compilable code snippet?

Comment: @Patrick, please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for this problem.

Comment: @reef @Oli Charlesworth @aioobe and @BalusC I've updated my question with the real implementation

Comment: Maybe you can clean you're dev environment, I know sometimes my eclipse is a little bit lost...

Comment: @reef I'm running it from terminal. I've updated my question with the dependencies I'm using.

Comment: Do you call getType() on document (a variable not showed in your example) or on _document (the lucene API Document instance in your example)? Because I cannot find any getType() method on the lucene Document doc (see http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html).

Comment: @reef Sorry you right, getType is returning a String. It is in a method defined by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that your `document.getType()` method returns a String and there 
is no constructor in the `Field` class that matches your call.
See http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html.

If I test your code in my environment Eclipse says:

> The constructor Field(String, String) is undefined

Maybe you could do as the following:

```
Document _document = new Document();
_document.add(new Field("type", document.getType().getBytes(), Store.YES);
// Or document.add(new Field("type", document.getType().getBytes(), Store.NO);
```

UPDATE after source code submission --------------------

The problem comes from the fact that in your class you have an inner-class called Document. There is a name conflict between your Document class and the Lucene's one. When you instanciate your document with the line `Document _document = new Document();` you're actually instanciating YOUR Document class. That's why the compiler cannot find the `add` method.

Multiple solution:

a. Instanciate the Document prefixing it with the Lucene package name

```
org.apache.lucene.document.Document _document = new org.apache.lucene.document.Document();
```

b. Rename your inner class so that you don't have any name conflict.

Comment: @reef I get this error: cannot find symbol: method getBytes() (and I imported java.io.Reader)

Comment: Your getType() method returns a String? In my example I call the constructor Field(String name, byte[] value, Field.Store store) so you don't need to import java.io.Reader. The getBytes() method called in my example comes from the String class (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: @reef Please, ignore my last message. I'm still getting the same error and my code is now: document.add(new Field("type", new byte[3], Field.Store.YES));

Comment: I don't understand however why you want me too add Store variable since I can omit it, according to documentation: Field(String name, Reader reader)

Comment: That was just an example of own to properly create a Field. You can use the constructor with the Reader instead of course ;)

Comment: So you still have the issue? The same message (cannot find symbol)?

Comment: @reef yes, same error. I still have it. I can attach all code if you want. This is the file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/CollectionIndexer.java

Comment: Ok got it. The problem comes from the fact that you have an internal class named Document and when you make new Document() you're instanciating your inner-class instead of the Lucene one.

Comment: First solution: you can instanciate your document using the package name of the lucene class: org.apache.lucene.document.Document _document = new org.apache.lucene.document.Document();

Comment: Second solution: rename your inner-class to be sure to avoid name conflict between your Document and the Lucene's one.

Answer (score 3):

When I'm stumped over this type of error, it is usually due to the fact that I've two definitions of `InterfaceName`, and accidentally imported the wrong one in one or more places.

(Happens for instance when I accidentally choose `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List` when auto-importing missing classes.)

Make sure that ...

```
symbol  : method methodName(org.bla.blabla.myClass)
                            \____________________/
                               ... this part ...
```

... matches the expected package / class.

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on updates to question:

- Make sure your curly braces around this line up and that there is not something else causing an issue.
- Reduce the code down just to as few lines as possible to eliminate any other items that could be throughing the compiler off.
- Compile without the `commons-digester-2.1` if you can, to eliminate possible conflicts.
- Break the line up so the a Field object is created on a separate line than adding the field to the document so that you can confirm there is no problem with your constructor call.